# dynamically calculation of multiple select option data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my form there is 5 nationality selection box with data-value in it.

```
<select id="visitorcount" name="visitorcount">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="person1">
    <select id="country1" name="visitor1">
        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="person2" style="display:none">
    <select id="country2" name="visitor2">
        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="person3" style="display:none">
    <select id="country3" name="visitor3" style="display:none">
        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="person4" style="display:none">
    <select id="country4" name="visitor4" style="display:none">
        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="person5" style="display:none">
    <select id="country5" name="visitor5" style="display:none">
        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="totalcost"></div>
```

first option is static and always present in form and other 4 select will be shown only when we select number of visitors.

Now what i want is, when i select option 1 it should show the data-fee value in div totalcost. 
when we select option two then it should show option1 + Option 2 data-fee value, and so on similar with all other select option.
and when we reduce the number of visitor, it should reduce the cost.

i am just not able to understand how to deal with this.

i can get cost of first select option like this but do not how to deal with dynamically, showing and hiding the div according to number of visitor and then select the options and get the prices and reduce the prices when reduce number of visitor.

```
<script>
    $('body').on('change', '#country1', function() {
        var priceforcountry = $('option:selected', this).data('fee');
        $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
        //alert(priceforcountry);
    });
</script>
```

and when we select country in option 1 it should auto select the same option in all other 4 select boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

You can use each by class selector for dynamic then check css `display`

```js
$('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
      $('#person' + i).show();
      $('#country' + i).show();
    } else {
      $('#person' + i).hide();
      $('#country' + i).hide();
    }
  }
});
$('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
  var priceforcountry = 0;
  $('.ct').each(function(index,element){
    if($(element).parent().css("display") != "none"){
      priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
    }
  });
  $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
  //alert(priceforcountry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="visitorcount" name="visitorcount">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="person1">
  <select id="country1" name="visitor1" class="ct">
    <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
    <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="person2" style="display:none" >
  <select id="country2" name="visitor2" class="ct">
    <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
    <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="person3" style="display:none">
  <select id="country3" name="visitor3" style="display:none" class="ct">
    <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
    <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="person4" style="display:none">
  <select id="country4" name="visitor4" style="display:none" class="ct">
    <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
    <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="person5" style="display:none">
  <select id="country5" name="visitor5" style="display:none" class="ct">
    <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
    <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="totalcost"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, this is what exactly i wanted, but there is one problem, the first nationality box is out of the person 1 div.. that is showing global... 

i want you to take a look at 

https://russiavisa.gyev.org/en2

Comment: use `if (i = 1){... use global element}`

Comment: ohh ok i see add `ct` class on global too

Comment: i tried to add CT class, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: you there, why above fiddle is not working as per your code. that i pasted just above this comment,

Comment: Ok. I have found solution `if ($(element).parent().is(":visible"))` will detect object truly hidden not by `.css()`

Comment: one more help i needed, when we select first option, like if i select USA in first option, USA should be auto selected in other options by default when we show other divs by number of visitors..

how can we do this?

Comment: add `$('.ct').trigger('change');` last of `$(document).ready`

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you add this in your fiddle.

Comment: I checked fiddle, and its not working.  my question is the country selected in first option, should be auto selected in other options.

Comment: but if i change first then change other will be change all

Comment: its working fine, i have checked it....

https://russiavisa.gyev.org/en2 check this form here.

Comment: try select country1 > add person > change country 1 > add person

Comment: thanks, you were right, and thanks for the fix, now its working perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198514/discussion-between-gaurav-singh-and-im-limit).